# Add prediction word in English and Gujarati in my custom keyboard suggestion

Tags: android

[image]

Add prediction word in English and Gujarati in my custom keyboard suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an entry into UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI table using ContentProvider API. 
Ref's : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics

Example code : 
https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-userdictionary-content-provider-insert-update-delete-fetch-example-using-contentvalues-contentresolver-and-uri

Use UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE column to set the language.

Comment: i implement but where is the prediction word?

Comment: In the above example, 
`ContentValues conValues = new ContentValues();
conValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE, "hi-IN");
conValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.WORD, "Mahesh");`
Here "Mahesh" is the word which will be added to dictionary.

Comment: i added but how can i get prediction word into gujarati or english.